# Добавление в связующую таблицу (many to many) через JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Есть бд, в ней 2 сущности и связь many to many, создаю DAO для crud операций, далее возникает вопрос, я хочу создать developer и добавить ему skill. Как мне добавить данные в таблицу skills_developers?

```
    /*Create table developers*/

    CREATE TABLE developers (
      id   INT          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
      salary VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    );

    /*Create table skills*/

    CREATE TABLE skills (
      id   INT          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    );

    /*Create table skill_developers with links*/

    CREATE TABLE skills_developers (
      dev_id    INT NOT NULL,
      sk_id     INT NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY (dev_id) REFERENCES developers (id),
      FOREIGN KEY (sk_id) REFERENCES skills (id)
    );

public void addDevSkills(String dev_name, String sk_name) {
    String sql = "INSERT  INTO skills_developers (dev_id, sk_id) " +
            "SELECT developers.id, skills.id " +
            "FROM developers, skills " +
            "WHERE d.name = ? AND s.name = ?";
    try (Connection connection = ApplicationJDBC.getConnection()) {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, developer.getFullName());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, skill.getName());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Почему не добавляет в таблицу??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO skills_developers (dev_id, sk_id)
SELECT d.id, s.id
FROM developers d, skills s
WHERE d.name = '?' AND s.name = '?';
```

В параметрах передаём фамилие персоны и фамилие его умелки.

PS. И неплохо бы сделать

```
ALTER TABLE skills_developers 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (dev_id, sk_id);
```

Ну так, чтобы случайно два раза не добавить...

Comment: Сам запрос рабочий но вот почему то через connection не добавляет в таблицу

Comment: *запрос рабочий но вот почему то через connection не добавляет* Значит, где-то в Сonnection напахано... например, косяк с кодировками или там кавычки в данных. Ошибок или предупреждений - нет? Посмотрите в General Log - добирается ли запрос до сервера, и если да - то в каком виде.

Comment: Я бы хотел изначально сделать так : выбрать все ID скиллов и потом по одному getById - добавлять в коллекцию нашего разаботчика. Но застопорился

Comment: Вы что, список скиллов в запрос передавать пытаетесь? *Я бы хотел изначально сделать так* Пытаетесь переплюнуть SQL-сервер в части эффективности обработки данных? напрасно...